# Powershell - parse CSV input with a specifiable delimiter

Tags: powershell, csv, delimiter, separator

How can I separate the data below into two columns delimited by semicolon?

```
GROUPING;SERIAL NUMBER              
-----------------------             
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA;18137521400329 
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA;18225521400335 
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA;18225521400341
```

My expected output is:

```
GROUPING               SERIAL NUMBER              
--------               --------------             
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA   18137521400329 
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA   18225521400335 
\\SDD\GMRN\CMM\KAYHA   18225521400341
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: im still searching.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing you the solution I've found:

When importing csv file, use (`-Delmiter`) :

```
 $csvfile = Import-Csv -Path $Dialog.FileName -Delimiter ";"
```